# Access specific field in struct which is in slice Golang templates

Tags: go, struct, slice, go-templates

I have such where I send to template years data (which is slice of structs). How can I access on template side `AcaYear` field of only 2nd item (struct)? Whole second item I can access as `{{index . 1 }}`. I also can range over slice and get `AcaYear` fields of both all items. But need only `AcaYear` field of second item (result should be `2021-2022`).

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type course struct {
    Number string
    Name   string
    Units  string
}

type semester struct {
    Term    string
    Courses []course
}

type year struct {
    AcaYear string
    Fall    semester
    Spring  semester
    Summer  semester
}

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("tpl.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    years := []year{
        year{
            AcaYear: "2020-2021",
            Fall: semester{
                Term: "Fall",
                Courses: []course{
                    course{"CSCI-40", "Introduction to Programming in Go", "4"},
                    course{"CSCI-130", "Introduction to Web Programming with Go", "4"},
                    course{"CSCI-140", "Mobile Apps Using Go", "4"},
                },
            },
            Spring: semester{
                Term: "Spring",
                Courses: []course{
                    course{"CSCI-50", "Advanced Go", "5"},
                    course{"CSCI-190", "Advanced Web Programming with Go", "5"},
                    course{"CSCI-191", "Advanced Mobile Apps With Go", "5"},
                },
            },
        },
        year{
            AcaYear: "2021-2022",
            Fall: semester{
                Term: "Fall",
                Courses: []course{
                    course{"CSCI-40", "Introduction to Programming in Go", "4"},
                    course{"CSCI-130", "Introduction to Web Programming with Go", "4"},
                    course{"CSCI-140", "Mobile Apps Using Go", "4"},
                },
            },
            Spring: semester{
                Term: "Spring",
                Courses: []course{
                    course{"CSCI-50", "Advanced Go", "5"},
                    course{"CSCI-190", "Advanced Web Programming with Go", "5"},
                    course{"CSCI-191", "Advanced Mobile Apps With Go", "5"},
                },
            },
        },
    }

    err := tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, years)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply group the `index` call and apply the `.AcaYear` field selector on the result:

```
{{ (index . 1).AcaYear }}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/stUu8VRdHyi)):

```
2021-2022
```